# Term for reading a legal document describing procedures and implementing those procedures in a computer system?

Tags: legal-terms

I was just reading some legal documents which described procedures which would be implemented in a computer system.  Is there a legal term to describe this action?

Comment: Are these legal documents regulations that prohibit actions, contracts that require actions, or what?

Comment: @user6726 These documents are Internal Controls.

Comment: It's just called "reading."

Comment: It doesn't sound like they are legal documents, unless you mean company-internal contractual policies relating to employment.